# How to work with someone else's Jupyter Notebook and virtualenv?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Jupyter Notebooks and I must be missing something that is entirely obvious to everyone else so apologies for the stupid question.

I have been given a Jupyter Notebook (in Python) that imports a few third-party modules that seem to be installed in the environment of the person who created it, ie it starts with a cell with code like this:

```py
from xxx import yyy
import zzz
```

I now need to install those dependencies and I naively assumed I could do this inside the iPython Notebook in a venv for this project and then activate that venv and run the Notebook with it like this:

```
python3 -m venv project_env
source project_env/bin/activate
pip install somestuff
```

But of course that doesn't work because I would have to run the above in a cell as BASH code which will spawn a subprocess and exit, thus the venv will not be available to the next cell.

I have seen [instructions](https://saturncloud.io/blog/running-jupyter-notebook-in-a-virtual-environment-installed-scikitlearn-module-not-available/#:%7E:text=Running%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20in%20a%20virtual%20environment%20is%20essential%20for,on%20your%20project%20with%20confidence.)  to install and register a new kernel on the server for this process but that doesn't seem ideal to me because I want to share the Notebook with others too and was hoping for the Notebook to contain all the data necessary to run it, including the creation of a venv with the correct versions of libraries that need to be installed.

This seems such a basic usecase to me, is there really no solution for this? What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "I naively assumed I could do this inside the iPython Notebook". You should be able to but you have realized why that won't work in the next paragraph. But the Jupyter developers built in a way to insure this works. If you are using anaconda/conda, run in your notebook `%conda install -c <proper_channel> xxx`. If the package xxx or zzz doesn't have a conda recipe or you aren't using Ancaonda/conda, use (or fall back) to running `%pip install xxx` in a cell in your notebook. After running either of those restart the kernel and try the import.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands added a few years ago to insure the installation occurs in the proper environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb` file. Don't follow any advice that says to use an exclamation point with install commands inside a notebook. That is outdated and can lead to issues and in fact was part of why the magic commands were added to make it more user-friendly and universal.

Comment: And if you need a way to share it with other, docker is an alternative to provide the environment if it is more complex than you can install with Ancaonda/conda or pip. Or if you can share at least the environment publically, you can define that in a customized repository via [conda with `environment.yml`](https://github.com/binder-examples/conda) or [pip with a `requirements.txt`](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements). Then using a `launch` badge  your users can get a temporary Binder session with that environment. If the notebook can be public you can put it so it is in the ...

Comment: <continued> session already when it starts up. Or your users will already have the notebook and you can tell them how to drag-and-drop it from their local machine into the Jupyter file navigation panel on the left when the session starts up. And then they can work with it there. They'd need to save anything useful they make back to their own machine as the session is temporary and anonymous. For security there's no way to get back anything made. You could also make a JupyterHub yourself for providing something more persistent with the environment and content you specify.

Comment: thank you so much @Wayne I knew I was missing something obvious. I did actually try the magic commands but I tried ```%source``` to activate a venv and that didn't work. I tried to just do ```%pip install``` and that does actually work, thanks a lot! Would you mind posting as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For installing from inside an active Jupyter `.ipynb` file, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands added a few years ago to insure the installation occurs in the proper environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb` file. In your case. that would be in the virtualenv; using the magic install command you can let Jupyter handle it properly with a single, user-friendly command.

From the comments, I know you were using `pip` for that package, and so the magic install command for running inside the active `.ipynb` file would be:

```py
%pip install xxx
```

###### Further details

If you are using anaconda/conda, run in your notebook `%conda install -c <proper_channel> xxx`. If the package xxx or zzz doesn't have a conda recipe or you aren't using Ancaonda/conda, use (or fall back) to running `%pip install xxx` in a cell in your notebook. **After running either of those restart the kernel and try the import.**

Note that when installed from inside the running notebook, sometimes very complex installations don't fully work even after restarting the kernel. This is very rare. It is usually is packages that involve a lot of communication with the inner working of Jupyter and/or involve javascript & sometimes hardware. I don't know if this would be helped by a full restart of everything; however, I'm usually on remote systems backed by docker and can switch to having it installed during the build.

---

---

For those seeking help on the more broader scope of sharing active Jupyter with someone, note that I included comments to the OP on some ways you can share environments where what is needed is already installed.