# Error trying to install Variable Explorer in Jupyter "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widgetsnbextension' "

Tags: python, module, jupyter

Working with Windows 10, Python 3.11.2, Jupyter 4.0.4

Following the instructions in

https://saturncloud.io/blog/what-is-the-variable-explorer-in-jupyter-notebook-and-how-to-use-it/

The first part works fine, and I did it in the command prompt

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

But the 2nd part

```
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

I run it in a Jupyter cell, and got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda3\Scripts\jupyter-nbextension-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 980, in start
    super().start()
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 243, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 888, in start
    self.toggle_nbextension_python(self.extra_args[0])
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 861, in toggle_nbextension_python
    return toggle(module,
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 474, in enable_nbextension_python
    return _set_nbextension_state_python(True, module, user, sys_prefix,
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 372, in _set_nbextension_state_python
    m, nbexts = _get_nbextension_metadata(module)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 1114, in _get_nbextension_metadata
    m = import_item(module)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 38, in import_item
    return __import__(parts[0])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widgetsnbextension'
```

This was also installed: `Successfully installed widgetsnbextension-4.0.9`

I guess the error is because I installed Python directly, and the command in Juypyter looks at the `C:\Miniconda3` directory.

1. How can I do to make Jupyter look at the right directory instead 'Miniconda'?
2. Is there another way to enable the `widgetsnbextension`

Comment: Do you mean JupyterLab 4.0.4? What you are attempting won't work in JupyterLab as extensions of that type don't work there. You'd want NbClassic these days if you need to run such extensions. Additionally, you are following outdated advice to use an exclamation point in conjunction with install commands. That is known to cause issues and that was a big reason why the magic install commands were added a few years ago now. You'll have a much easier time if you follow current best practices, see my comment ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77136355/how-to-work-with-someone-elses-jupyter-notebook-and-virtualenv/77143574#comment135983679_77136355) and the one below it for more about this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) for more about NbClassic.

Comment: Thanks for que quick answer! So I going the wrong way... !

Comment: You didn't really provide me any additional information. Are you using JupyterLab? If so ... Keep in mind the debugger comes by default in JupyterLab and you can use it to explore variables, see more about it [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html). (Keep in mind that those images may not match 100% given the fast pace of development.) I just used it in JupyterLab 4.0.3 by clicking on the bug icon on the left and then clicking the orange bug next to my notebook's kernel in the upper right above the notebook. Ran the notebook & the variables featured in top pane.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Jupyter. I thought I was installing some sort of 'variable inspector', similar we have in Spyder, R-Studio or Matlab. I tried this https://github.com/lckr/jupyterlab-variableInspector but it didn't work. But as you said, that was outdated and not for the purpose I want. Some suggestion about?

Comment: "Yes, I'm using Jupyter."  I assume you mean 'JupyterLab', by "Jupyter" since that link refers to JupyterLab. There are several interfaces now that are all Jupyter and so it is important to specify well now. Especially since there is Jupyter Notebook 7. This one is more up to date [here](https://github.com/zhangfeiran/jupyterlab-variableInspector) but I didn't have luck with it. "not for the purpose I want." -- What do you want?  The Debugger doesn't suffice?

Comment: Yes, JupyterLab!

Comment: Yes, I use JupyterLab! Sorry I'm not from the 'computer science', so maybe I can't express myself correctly.  I want a 'variable inspector'! The sort of inspector we can check the variables in the workspace, their size, type, etc. I get used to work without one (in JupyterLab), but it is quite annoying checking with type(), shape(), len(), etc... In fact, I would like to have something like this github.com/lckr/jupyterlab-variableInspector, but working!

Comment: I suspect the separate Variable inspector development ceased because the Variable panel in the built in Debugger covers the same territory. How does the Variable panel within the Debugger not cover your needs? You can always provide feedback via the issues page at any of the GitHub repos for the involved sites